# Why my lambda query is throwing error while picking a single column?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, c#-4.0

I am trying to pick only single column but it throws error that queryable collection cannot be converted to integer.

```
public int GetID(int ID)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(uow.repo.GetQueryable()
                .Where(rh => rh.ID == ID && rh.Status == 0)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev).Select(s => s.ID));
    return ID;
}
```

Comment: check the documentation of `Select` to see what the return value is

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert a collection into an int.

Since the collection holds (possibly) multiple int's this isn't well defined and hence the error.

To fix it, you must make sure you select only one int.

E.g.:

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(
          uow.repo.GetQueryable()
                  .Where(rh => rh.ID== ID && rh.Status == 0)
                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev)
                  .Select(s=>s.ID) //this still is a collection
                  .First()); //this takes the first one.
```

*In spirit of @Mong Zo's comment:*

---

You have a few more possibilities to fix this:

[.First()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8) <sub>**this will throw an error if the collection is empty**</sub>

[.Single()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8), <sub>**this will throw an error if the collection does not contain exactly 1 item**</sub>

Then there are also:

[.SingleOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8) and [.FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) which are similar, but both dó allow an empty list.

*Note:*: `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` will make `Convert.ToInt32` return `0` is the list is empty.

Comment: may be `Single` or `First` would be a better choice to avoid accidentally ending up with an `ID` of `0` without really noticing it. Or use a nullable `int?`

Answer (score 0):

there are few points here

-> I think  uow.repos id column is already int type(i dont know how did you defined it)
if it is then you dont need to convert that to int cos its already is in int

```
  public int GetID(int ID)
    { 
    return (uow.repo.GetQueryable()
                    .Where(rh => rh.ID == ID && rh.Status == 0)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev).First(s => s.ID)); 
    }
```

-> if its not an integer type then i would recomend something like this

```
public int GetID(int ID)
{ 
return (Convert.ToInt32(uow.repo.GetQueryable()
                .Where(rh => rh.ID == ID && rh.Status == 0)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev).First(s => s.ID))); 
}
```

if its nullable int then you should try implicit convert

```
public int GetID(int ID)
{ 
return ((int)uow.repo.GetQueryable()
                .Where(rh => rh.ID == ID && rh.Status == 0)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev).First(s => s.ID)); 
}
```